# angular 4 rerouting-component does not reload

Tags: angular, angular5, ngrx-store

I have a component that:

1. Loads **router-outlet** into view
2. In its constructor: Subscribe to an ngrx Store veriable which is initialized already
3. In its constructor: nevigate to a relevant sub-path/child-component based on that veriable.

ReRoutingComponent.ts

```
export class ReRoutingComponent implements OnInit {
HOF$:Observable<any>;
HOF:any;

isUHC:boolean;
constructor(
    private _store:Store<any>,
    private _router:Router,
    private _route:ActivatedRoute
) {
    this.HOF$ = _store.select(from_costumer.getHOF);
    this.HOF$.subscribe((v:any)=> {
        this.HOF = v;
        this.isUHC = this.HOF['isUHC'];
        if(this.isUHC) {
            this._router.navigate(['../uscostumer'], {relativeTo: this._route});
        }else {
            this._router.navigate(['../globalcostumer'], {relativeTo: this._route});
        }
    });
}
ngOnInit() {

}
}
```

So the path **domain.com/site/providers** re-routes to **domain.com/site/providers/globalcostumer** by default and to **domain.com/site/providers/uscostumer** if the ngrx variable was assigned.

Im navigating to **domain.com/site/providers** using a simple **[router-link]** directive, not via **_router.navigate**.

**The Problem**

1. When I navigate back to **ReRoutingComponent.ts** or **domain.com/site/providers** using the same **router-outlet** link, The **ReRoutingComponent.ts** constructor does not run, the component is not reloaded and the ngrx subscription does not re-route to the relevant component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ngOnInit` lifecycle hook to do these stuffs and it will be called everytime you route to it.

```
export class ReRoutingComponent implements OnInit {
HOF$:Observable<any>;
HOF:any;
subscription;
isUHC:boolean;
constructor(
    private _store:Store<any>,
    private _router:Router,
    private _route:ActivatedRoute
) {}

ngOnInit() {
   this.HOF$ = _store.select(from_costumer.getHOF);
   this.subscription = this.HOF$.subscribe((v:any)=> {
        this.HOF = v;
        this.isUHC = this.HOF['isUHC'];
        if(this.isUHC) {
            this._router.navigate(['../uscostumer'], {relativeTo: this._route});
        }else {
            this._router.navigate(['../globalcostumer'], {relativeTo: this._route});
        }
    });        
}

ngOnDestroy() {
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}

}
```

Comment: **this.HOF$.unsubscribe();** will tield an error since the **unsubscribe()** is defined on the returned value from the **this.HOF$.subscribe();** statement. so it is this.subscription = this.HOF$.subscribe(...); this.subscription.unsubscribe()

Comment: I have updated my answer. You can accept the answer if it solved your problem